# Compare values from a single array with multiple series of arrays, then echo the result

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, compare, echo

With the following script I am able to calculate the **frequency** of every number from 10 different arrays, then echoes the result sorting the numbers in frequency classes (ex. values that appear one time : x, y, z , values that appear two times : a, b, c, ....etc.)

```
<?php $set1 = ['23', '11', '52', '33', '1', '4'];
$set2 = ['66', '70', '55', '8', '22', '1'];
$set3 = ['38', '21', '52', '51', '53', '9'];
$set4 = ['14', '31', '54', '5', '73', '39'];
$set5 = ['10', '3', '22', '59', '73', '39'];
$set6 = ['22', '13', '4', '5', '73', '39']
$set7 = ['40', '3', '22', '5', '13', '30'];
$set8 = ['88', '53', '4', '25', '71', '19'];
$set9 = ['10', '30', '49', '25', '73', '46'];
$set10 = ['10', '3', '4', '5', '73', '11'];

$mergedArray = array_merge($set1, $set2, $set3, $set4, $set5, $set6, $set7, $set8, $set9, $set10);
echo 'Values that appear 1 time: ' . implode(', ', array_keys(getRepeatedNumber($mergedArray, 1))) . '<br>';
echo 'Values that appear 2 times: ' . implode(', ', array_keys(getRepeatedNumber($mergedArray, 2))) . '<br>';
echo 'Values that appear 3 times: ' . implode(', ', array_keys(getRepeatedNumber($mergedArray, 3))) . '<br>';
echo 'Values that appear 4 times: ' . implode(', ', array_keys(getRepeatedNumber($mergedArray, 4))) . '<br>';
echo 'Values that appear 5 times: ' . implode(', ', array_keys(getRepeatedNumber($mergedArray, 5))) . '<br>';
function getRepeatedNumber($mergedArray, $requiredCount)
{
$counts = array_count_values($mergedArray);
$requiredResult = array_filter($counts, function ($value) use ($requiredCount) {
    return $value == $requiredCount;
});
return $requiredResult;}
```

My problem :
I would like to calculate the frequency and echo the result of an extra array of numbers that should be **compared** with the actual set of arrays of my script.

For example :
If I have

```
$extraset = ['1', '4', '52'] ;
```

i would like to

- check how many times those numbers appear in the $set1 to $set10 arrays
- echo the result sorting the numbers in frequency classes like now.

but I don't understand how to compare the $extraset  (i am a real newbie..!)

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the problem as a conversion problem. You are converting numbers to their frequency and vice versa. `array_count_values` sets up a table of conversions as an array. The keys of the array, gives the numbers to convert and their values their frequency.

So start off with building up the merged arrays:

```
$set1 = ['23', '11', '52', '33', '1', '4'];
$set2 = ['66', '70', '55', '8', '22', '1'];
$set3 = ['38', '21', '52', '51', '53', '9'];
$set4 = ['14', '31', '54', '5', '73', '39'];
$set5 = ['10', '3', '22', '59', '73', '39'];
$set6 = ['22', '13', '4', '5', '73', '39']
$set7 = ['40', '3', '22', '5', '13', '30'];
$set8 = ['88', '53', '4', '25', '71', '19'];
$set9 = ['10', '30', '49', '25', '73', '46'];
$set10 = ['10', '3', '4', '5', '73', '11'];

$mergedArray = array_merge($set1, $set2, $set3, $set4, $set5, $set6, $set7, $set8, $set9, $set10);
```

Next set up the conversion table:

```
$frequencies = array_count_values($mergedArray);
```

Then set up the inverse lookup of this table (keys are counts, values are numbers):

```
$inverse_frequencies = [];
foreach ($frequencies as $number => $count) {
    $inverse_frequencies[$count][] = $number;
}
```

Sort this, so the keys (counts) are ascending for display purposes:

```
ksort($inverse_frequencies);
```

And display them:

```
foreach ($inverse_frequencies as $count => $numbers_array) {
    echo "Values that appear $count times: " . implode(', ', $numbers_array) . '<br>';
}
```

This method is more general and flexible than the one you gave.

Next we take the `$extraset` array and loop through to find the frequency of each element and display it:

```
$extraset = ['1', '4', '52'] ;

foreach ($extraset as $element) {
    $frequency = $frequencies[$element]??0;
    echo "Extraset element '$element' appears $frequency times<br>";
}
```

Note the use of of the null coalescing operator `??` just in case we can't find the number in the frequency list.

**EDIT**

You could improve on the way the sets are handled, by pushing each new set into an array and then merging (ideally you would put this in a function):

```
$sets = [];
$sets[] = ['23', '11', '52', '33', '1', '4'];
$sets[] = ['66', '70', '55', '8', '22', '1'];
$sets[] = ['38', '21', '52', '51', '53', '9'];
$sets[] = ['14', '31', '54', '5', '73', '39'];
$sets[] = ['10', '3', '22', '59', '73', '39'];
$sets[] = ['22', '13', '4', '5', '73', '39'];
$sets[] = ['40', '3', '22', '5', '13', '30'];
$sets[] = ['88', '53', '4', '25', '71', '19'];
$sets[] = ['10', '30', '49', '25', '73', '46'];
$sets[] = ['10', '3', '4', '5', '73', '11'];

$mergedArray = [];
foreach ($sets as $set) {
    $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $set);
}
```

That allows you to have an indexed set of arrays (`$sets`), the ones with higher indexes are newer.

You can then search the `$sets` array in reverse to find the most recent instance of a number:

```
$reverse_sets = array_reverse($sets);

foreach ($extraset as $element) {
    foreach ($reverse_sets as $index => $set) {
        if (in_array($element, $set)) {
            $actual_index = count($reverse_sets)-$index-1;
            echo "Extraset element '$element' is in set $actual_index<br>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to fixup the `$index` because reversing the array re-indexes it (the keys are not kept).

You need `break` so that as soon as you find a value, you move on to the next value.

I'll leave it up to you how you handle elements which are not found.

Comment: This is really instructive thanks. Could it work also to calculate delays ? For example could I be able to echo last time the numbers of the extra set were seen into the arrays sets ? Stating that $set1 is the older while $set10 is the newer ? Thanks again for your help

Comment: thanks, i have put it online, but it prints wrong results (52 is found on set 2, but that is not the most recent and not even the older. Link : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f3fb4136ead25dba4f5cb09bbf47bc59303925df  Maybe i did something wrong ? thanks for your patience

Comment: No it's correct. Indexes start from zero. Set 2 is the most recent set with 52 in.